Sovol SV06 Plus extruder issues
My SV06 Plus printed fine for a few months and then all of a sudden it started clogging really badly so I tore it down and cleaned it well, greased all the appropriate parts and such. Then I put it back together and made the mistake of screwing the nozzle in cold, so it sheared off. I couldn't get the back half of the nozzle out, so I ordered a new hot end. the part got here worked great for one print and then it clogged really bad. there were broken pieces of un-melted PLA in the housing for the gears and the hot end clogged as well. I cleaned it out and put the nozzle back in correctly this time was inserting it at 260 °C, when it sheared off again.
I'm very frustrated by this and don't understand what I'm doing wrong I'm still new-ish to printing and want to learn how to do it well but the YouTube stuff doesn't help a lot can anyone tell me what I did wrong in this instance and how to fix it.

I always screw the nozzles in cold for years, never had one shearing off. Assembling hot is really not necessary. Aren't you using too much force?

i could be honestly the svo6 plus has these proprietary nozzles that are really long. ive been thinking about switching out the hot end to the regular svo6 that takes the standard short nozzles.

I'm pretty sure an over-access amount of force has been used when screwing in nozzles. This is just not supposed to happen, I haven't seen this the past 10 years in my printing endeavors or those near me.
The advice to use heat when screwing in nozzles comes from the fact that cold hardened filament may prevent you to correctly screw in a different nozzle against the heatbreak, but when it is new, or properly cleaned this is absolutely not necessary, I have never done this for a range of printers and never had a leaking hotend.
To prevent overtightening of the nozzle, you could print (once you ordered a new hot end, or buy) a torque wrench. One of 2.5 Nm should do fine, see e.g. Thingiverse for examples. I've printed these and they work great.
